# How to Extract Text from Body HTML

Tags: html, text

I have an HTML element that displays text documents like so:

```
<embed src="Link" type="text/html" width="100%" height="427px" />
```

"Link" being the link to the text document in external storage.

The text in the document is displayed in the body of the page. I need to be able to extract the displayed text and send it out of the HTML element to the outer page be edited; however if I use:

```
document.getElementById("Body").innerHTML
```

It just displays the link to the document and not the text itself. Is there a way of copying the displayed text in the body, with code, to be edited?

Example of what is output:

```
<embed src="Link" type="text/html" width="100%" height="427px">
```

What should be output:

```
Text that is contained in the text file.
```

Comment: `<embed>` is not an `iframe`, js `getElementById` gets element by id, like `<p id="here">blah</p>`. Please, explain with more details "and send it out" - to where and how? By the way `<embed>` is depreciated, no more supported, you should replace it.

Comment: Sorry i meant an HTML iframe element in wix so <iframe> is not used. <embed> is the part with the file. I shall make the changes. "Send it out" means to send it out of the HTML element to the outside page, I can do that, I just need to know how to read the text from the text document.

Comment: add  id="Body"  to it and you should get the text

Comment: Thank you, where in the code do I add that?

Comment: It just outputs the link.

Comment: You can't do that with js. `embed` content is not part of your page `<html><body> your page <embed> <html> ...  embedded page ... </html></embed> your page </body></html>`. If it is only one page and one txt (or several) the best way is to manually `copy - save as` this text. You can edit this embedded content with your browser developer tools if you want html tags etc., just copy and paste into Notepad. If there is more to it than you can do by hand, then it's `scraping` and I can't help you with that